# Windows Firewall and %USERPROFILE% variable

Tags: windows, firewall

I've discovered that using system variables as `%USERPROFILE%` in *Windows Firewall* path definition like `%USERPROFILE%\op\opera.exe` makes the firewall doesn't work for such defined application. Changing the path to an explicit definition like `C:\Users\Mark\op\opera.exe` does work.
My question is why can't one use `%USERPROFILE%` var in the firewall path definition?

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Firewall can't know which user's profile `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable point, it should know the exact path of the application to find it. Especially, if no user logged in, `%USERPROFILE%` points to where?